# Do we need to generate new IPW when doing subgroup analysis?

Tags: matching, treatment-effect, weights

I am working on a quasi-experimental study to compare an interventional and control arm. I have generated inverse-probability weights (IPW) and weighted the population (N=300) when estimating effect of interest. The study is also interested to look at a subgroup of diabetic patients (N=50) within the weighted population. Does it make sense to run the subgroup analysis using the same weights used to run the full analysis?

I think the answer is no because the the covariate balance may not be retained in the subgroup. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It is almost never a good idea to actually subset the data when you are interested in a "subgroup" (I put that in quotes because *subgroup* implies that the group is homogeneous, which it seldom is).  Add appropriate interactions to the model to estimates diabetes-specific effects.  This process will respect the IPWs.

Actually subsetting the data will lead to inefficient estimates of $\sigma$ in linear models and will not inherit needed covariate adjustment that was (hopefully) used in the fun model.  And it may also make it confusing to use weights.

I assume you have a compelling reason for using weights, which often inflate standard errors of parameter estimates of interest.